# Postgresql Could not serialize access due to concurrent update, how to find out why

Tags: django, postgresql, celery

Project use Django and Postgresql 9.5.  Sometimes I see the error in celery task.

When object need change specified column it uses celery task.
This task writes in separate table change history of an object and update column(not raw SQL, by Django ORM).
Task write history by FDW extension into the foreign table.

Thrown exception:

`Remote SQL command: COMMIT TRANSACTION\nSQL statement "SELECT 1 FROM ONLY "public"."incident_incident" x WHERE "id" OPERATOR(pg_catalog.=) $1 FOR KEY SHARE OF x"\n',)`

I can't take understand why it raises the exception. Task very simple

screen logs(maybe it help):
[image]
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In celery, when you are doing transaction, then you can use `transaction.atomic` block to do that.

For example:

```
@app.task(bind=True)
def do_task(self)
    try:
        with transaction.atomic():
           # Do DB OP
    except (SomeException,Exception) as exc:
        raise self.retry(exc=exc)
```

There are other approaches as well. You can add a new field regarding object change in Model and track it. You can read [this article on medium regarding this approach](https://medium.com/@hakibenita/how-to-manage-concurrency-in-django-models-b240fed4ee2). Hope it helps!!